# Why are the levels in a coxph in R being named strangely?

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am running a coxph with the formula

```
formula(Surv(followup, outcome) ~ cohort + pre_event)
```

In the cohort column I have 6 different categories set as a factor.

When I run instead of returning cohort.1, cohort.2 etc, the rownames are

```
cohort.L
cohort.Q
cohort.C
cohort^4
cohort^5
```

Why does it change them and how can I get it to stop? It isn't a length issue as I've changed the values to 0-6 rather than their actual names, and changed the word cohort to ch.

I can't provide a reprex because I can't get the model to converge with fewer than 50 or so events per category.

Comment: Could you share some reproducible data so we could recreate the problem?

Comment: @jpsmith sorry, as I said at the bottom I can't work out how to as the cox model doesn't want to converge without a large number of samples from each category.

Comment: `cohort` is an ordered factor in your data, you can set `factor(..., ordered = FALSE)`

Comment: here is a collection of answers about what these terms mean https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/498824/2126

Comment: Thank you @rawr, that helps. I've made it an unordered factor.

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker that's interesting reading. Wish it was more obvious elsewhere.